# Is there a way to display a number more than 12 characters whose format is TEXT

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2019

I know how to display a number more than 12 characters whose format is Number.

However, I downloaded an excel and when I open the sheet, I saw like "47821E+12" and I changed the format to TEXT but It won't change.

It still shows "47821E+12".

However, When I double click the cell and enter, It shows right like "47821573839123"

Is there an automated way to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your character count is smaller than 16, you can simply convert the cell type into 'number' which gives you the exact format instead of scientific one.

*Update*

If the cells has non-numeric charracters, you can try to convert the contents of cells via

```
=TEXT(A1, "0")
```

in a new cell, where A1 is the cell has scientific display.

Comment: The thing is I have alphabet characters in the same column. So I cannot convert the column format into Number

Comment: Oh I see then you can try to convert the contents in a new cell with 

=TEXT(A1, "0")

Where A1 is the cell that has scientific dispaly.

Comment: @Eric Lee: Why not? The alphabet characters will not be affected by the numeric format. Format Cells->Number->Number, Decimals 0. BTW, If the cells were formatted as text, you couldn't retrieve all digits.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I thought changing the format would affect the value in the cells. But It won't! Thanks for letting me know that.

Comment: This solution works fine! and the suggestion from @VBasic2008 also works fine too!